# Is it possible to delete contacts from Audience Manager in bulk using built in features?

Tags: audience-manager

We have a list of contacts that we would like to remove from Tridion altogether.  We would prefer to do this using either the upload file web service: 
**AudienceManager/Webservice/2013/IAudienceManagerWebservice2013/UploadFile**
or through the Content Manager Interface using the Import Contacts feature in the context menu:
http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-DB1774DE-E764-4303-A1C7-294AFC11C4F3

The SDL docs make no mention of removing contacts using these features.  Is it possible to do this or would we have to do it manually?

Comment: There are 1000 contacts which you can select from GUI to delete at once. Guess not having much option to delete contacts from GUI is a safe measures for AM.You definitely can make API calls though to delete whatever contacts you want. call delete() of Item class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible to delete Contacts using either of those features. It is possible using Tridion.AudienceManagement.API (using the Contact.GetList and Contact.Delete methods).

Unfortunately you have to run that code on the Content Manager server itself; it is currently not possible to access that API remotely.